# what does command test -x do in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, logging, command

what does `test -x` from 
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate do?

```
test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Does it test if already executing file /usr/sbin/logrotate?

Answer (score 2):

```
test -x /path/to/file
```

It checks if `file` **exists** and is **executable** by current user

Answer (score 0):

Type `man test` in Google and it will find you a manual page that says this:

```
'-x file'
     True if file is executable.
```