# what is use of `test -x` in Perl script execution

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Perl !!!. I have one old crontab entry in sun OS machine to run a Perl script which goes like `10 * * * * test -x $path/abc.pl && $path/abc.pl >/dev/nul`.
I want to know what is the use of term `test -x` in this execution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704494/what-does-command-test-x-do-in-ubuntu

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=test+-x+%24path%2Fabc.pl+%26%26+%24path%2Fabc.pl+%3E%2Fdev%2Fnull

Comment: So it basically checks whether the user has enough permission to execute or not. It does not have any role in executing script, something like for a shell script we use `sh` i.e., `sh abc.sh` ?

Answer (score 3):

`test` check file types (and permissions).
`test -x FILE` checks that FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted.
So, only if `$path/abc.pl` is an existing file and the current user has execute permission, it will be executed.

Refernce:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/test

BTW, this has nothing to do with Perl, although Perl has similar function:
https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Comment: You might want to add that it has nothing to do with Perl.

Comment: @simbabque added. thanks.